# Apply a function with an rolling estimation window only on specific rows or dates of a dataframe

Tags: r, window-functions, rolling-computation

Is it possible to apply a function with a rolling window to this data frame:

```
Name Date    market_return  stock_return  RESULT
AAL  1.1.15   3%              5%
AAL  2.1.15   2%              1%
...
AAPL 1.1.15   3%              4%
AAPL 2.1.15   2%              3%
...
```

However only when matching these specific dates and Names:

```
Name Date    
AAL  4.4.15
AAL  15.6.15
...
AAPL 5.6.15
AAPL 5.7.15
...
```

The outcome should looke something like:

```
Name Date    market_return  stock_return  RESULT
AAL  1.1.15   3%              5%           NA
AAL  2.1.15   2%              1%           NA
...
AAL  4.4.15   3%              5%           xxx
...
AAL  15.6.15  3%              5%           xxx
...
AAPL 1.1.15   3%              4%           NA
AAPL 2.1.15   2%              3%           NA
...
AAPL 5.6.15   2%              5%           xxx
...
AAPL 5.7.15   2%              5%           xxx
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The question is not specific regarding the operation to perform so we shall assume it is sum.

In the Note at the end we first read the data into data frames, convert the `Date` columns to `Date` class and the `_return` columns to numeric.

Left join DF to DF2 on Name and Date and left join DF2 to DF on the date range and Name and then sum all stock_returns in the second instance of DF that are joined to each row of the first instance of DF.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.*, sum(b.stock_return) as RESULT
  from DF a
  left join DF2 c on a.Name = c.Name and a.Date = c.Date
  left join DF b on b.Date between c.Date - 185 and c.Date + 185 and 
    c.Name = b.Name
  group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
  Name       Date market_return stock_return RESULT
1  AAL 2015-01-01             3            3     NA
2  AAL 2015-01-02             2            2     NA
3  AAL 2015-04-04             3            3     11
4  AAL 2015-06-15             3            3     11
5 AAPL 2015-01-01             3            3     NA
6 AAPL 2015-01-02             2            2     NA
7 AAPL 2015-06-05             2            2      9
8 AAPL 2015-07-05             2            2      9
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Name Date    market_return  stock_return
AAL  1.1.15   3%              5%
AAL  2.1.15   2%              1%
AAL  4.4.15   3%              5%
AAL  15.6.15  3%              5%
AAPL 1.1.15   3%              4%
AAPL 2.1.15   2%              3%
AAPL 5.6.15   2%              5%
AAPL 5.7.15   2%              5%"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
DF <- transform(DF, Date = as.Date(Date, "%d.%m.%y"),
  market_return = as.numeric(sub("%", "", market_return)),
  stock_return = as.numeric(sub("%", "", stock_return)))

Lines <- "Name Date    
AAL  4.4.15
AAL  15.6.15
AAPL 5.6.15
AAPL 5.7.15"
DF2 <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
DF2$Date <- as.Date(DF2$Date, "%d.%m.%y")
```

### Update

Simplified.